# rJava for R Installation fails on Windows machine

Tags: r

I need to install rJava for R.

I've downloaded what I think is the 64-bit java from here:

https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

It's created the folder:

jre1.8.0_271

I've set that as the JAVA_HOME folder.

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271')

But still I have an error:

install.packages("rJava")

```
> 
* installing *source* package 'rJava' ...
** package 'rJava' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Generate Windows-specific files (src/jvm-w32) ...
make: Entering directory '/Users/cstangor/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmCAkum/R.INSTALL1a2c5d256e9a/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/dlltool --as C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/as  --input-def jvm64.def --kill-at --dllname jvm.dll --output-lib libjvm.dll.a
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -O2 -c -o findjava.o findjava.c
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -s -o findjava.exe findjava.o
make: Leaving directory '/Users/cstangor/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmCAkum/R.INSTALL1a2c5d256e9a/rJava/src/jvm-w32'
Find Java...
  JAVA_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/Java/JRE18~1.0_2
=== Building JRI ===
  JAVA_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/Java/JRE18~1.0_2
  R_HOME=C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0
JDK has no javah.exe - using javac -h . instead
Creating Makefiles ...
Configuration done.
make -C src JRI.jar
make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/cstangor/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmCAkum/R.INSTALL1a2c5d256e9a/rJava/jri/src'
C:/PROGRA~1/Java/JRE18~1.0_2/bin/javac -h . -d . ../RList.java ../RBool.java ../RVector.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../Mutex.java ../Rengine.java ../REXP.java ../RFactor.java ../package-info.java
sh: C:/PROGRA~1/Java/JRE18~1.0_2/bin/javac: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile.all:41: org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.class] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/cstangor/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmCAkum/R.INSTALL1a2c5d256e9a/rJava/jri/src'
make: *** [Makefile.all:19: src/JRI.jar] Error 2
**** WARNING: JRI could NOT be built
Set IGNORE=1 if you want to build rJava anyway.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'
* removing 'C:/Users/cstangor/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rJava'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have downloaded the Java runtime environment only.

rJava requires the full development kit available [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html).

Comment: I have installed the 64 bit version of the JDK.

Comment: If I point to the jdk subdirectory the error is different but it still doesn't install.  *....../Mutex.java ../Rengine.java ../REXP.java ../RFactor.java ../package-info.java
..\Rengine.java:120: error: invalid use of a restricted identifier 'yield....
        while (!alive && !died) yield();

Comment: Not really answered, but I found a workaround.  Thanks